# Adding a row in Spec results in a column?

Tags: widget, smalltalk, pharo, uibuilder, spec-ui

The current API of Spec is totally counter-intuitive. I am trying to stack up two rows in a SpecLayout. How is that adding a row ends up with two columns?

```
| m |
m := DynamicComposableModel new.
m instantiateModels: #(text1 TextModel ok OkToolbar).
m ok okAction: [ m window delete ].
m openWithSpecLayout: (SpecLayout composed
    newRow: [: r | r add: #text1 ; add: #ok ];
    yourself).
```

[image: SpecLayout with two columns]

and adding another TextModel will be placed as a new column... How to add real rows, as everybody understands them: one widget below or above, instead of adding them to the right or left (as columns)?

Comment: There are a couple of interesting **Spec** questions. We should see, if we could come up with a tag for those. Of course **Spec** is already taken. Perhaps **Spec-UI**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you add a row, and add items to row. And items of row are positioned horizontally. So if you want to position something vertically, you have to add it to column.